# Script to store HTML Table into excel worksheet automatically every day at a specific time

Tags: javascript, html, excel

There is this website having a table which I want to save everyday at 18:00 Hrs. into a excel sheet named with the date and time.

I have no idea of programming. I tried digging through Google and Stackoverflow and was able to figure out how to do it manually but I want this to be done everyday.
Here I will list out the procedure that I have figured out using the internet and I want to automate the same.

I go to this [webpage](http://nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/option_chain/optionKeys.jsp?symbolCode=-10003&symbol=NIFTY&symbol=NIFTY&instrument=-&date=-&segmentLink=17&symbolCount=2&segmentLink=17) and click on inspect element and obtain the html code of the table (search for "octable").
After getting the HTML code of the table, I run this javascript online using JSFiddle to get the excel file.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btnExport").click(function(e) {
        //getting values of current time for generating the file name
        var dt = new Date();
        var day = dt.getDate();
        var month = dt.getMonth() + 1;
        var year = dt.getFullYear();
        var hour = dt.getHours();
        var mins = dt.getMinutes();
        var postfix = day + "." + month + "." + year + "_" + hour + "." + mins;
        //creating a temporary HTML link element (they support setting file names)
        var a = document.createElement('a');
        //getting data from our div that contains the HTML table
        var data_type = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel';
        var table_div = document.getElementById('dvData');
        var table_html = table_div.outerHTML.replace(/ /g, '%20');
        a.href = data_type + ', ' + table_html;
        //setting the file name
        a.download = 'exported_table_' + postfix + '.xls';
        //triggering the function
        a.click();
        //just in case, prevent default behaviour
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

I want to do all this steps automatically at 18:00 hrs every weekday. Can someone please help me here? If possible, can the same script be run over a remote server and the files are saved in cloud like google drive or emailed to my account?

P.S.: Since I'm new here I don't have enough reputations to add images to the question :(

Answer (score 0):

You could use macros like iMacros, to pull from the source code and store in excel. You could also use python (if you want to code a script), to pull the data, maybe using something like beautifulsoup!

You could then use task scheduler (if in windows) or its alternative to execute the script or the macro!

Answer (score 0):

1) you can use imacro if you dont want to get to much into code

2) you can use perl, very easily like this:

script.pl :

```
use LWP::Simple;
my $url = 'http://example.com';
my $content = get $url;
##You can add all sorts of manipulations to the returned source
##You can use this method with more options like timeout and credentials 
my $outputPath = 'temp.csv';
open(my $fh, '>' , $outputPath) or die "could not open file '$outputPath' $! ";
print $fh . "\n" . localtime() . "," . $content;
```

you can run this in an infinite loop and save a copy as soon as you see a diff, you can parse certain parts of the page, you can run it at a certain time with windows task scheduler ect'